# Creating simple if statement in Python when pining IP address

Tags: python, ip, ping

I'm using: Windows I'm trying to create a simple `if` statement when pinging ip address

```
import os
hostname = "192.168.8.8." #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'is down'

else:
  print hostname, 'is up'

print response
```

I'm pretty new at this, but no matter what ip address I put, valid or not, it says it's up.

Answer (score 1):

*os.system() returns the process exit value. 0 means success.*

In your case it is getting executed successfully and hence it is returning 0. All you have to do is get the complete output from the ping command and then do string comparison to find out if that IP is alive.

You need to use [subprocess's checkoutput method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
import subprocess

hostname = "google.com"
batcmd="ping -n 1 " + hostname
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
if "Received = 1" in result:
    print "Is UP"
else:
    print "Is Down"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variation of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768878/detecting-internet-for-a-specific-interface-over-python/35769171#35769171) removing the interface argument `subprocess.check_call`:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError, PIPE

def is_reachable(i, add):
    command = ["ping", "-c", i, add]
    try:
        check_call(command,sdout=PIPE)
        return True
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        return False

if is_reachable("3", "127.0.0.01"):
 # host is reachable
else:
     # not reachable
```

On windows you may need to add the args `"-w", "2999"` to get something other than 0 returned for the errorlevel for unreachable hosts as the return code will be zero even for unsuccessful calls, [windows-7-get-no-reply-but-sets-errorlevel-to-0](https://superuser.com/questions/403905/ping-from-windows-7-get-no-reply-but-sets-errorlevel-to-0.)

You could also use *check_output*, specifically checking if `Destination host unreachable` was in the output:

```
 return "Destination host unreachable" in check_output(command)
```

Answer (score -1):

You did everything okay, The only issue is that you confused the correct output which is 0 with the wrong output, which is everything above 0.

```
import os
hostname = "192.168.8.8." #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
    print hostname, 'is up'

else:
  print hostname, 'is down'

print response
```

Comment: If that were True how would it always say up?

Comment: Maybe the IP that he entered was always wrong or invalid. You can check the code if you want to. Your response suggesting another function doesn't deal with the OP issue.

Comment: *but no matter what ip address I put valid or not it says it's up* should be pretty self explanatory, it could not wrong in both directions

Comment: I say that if you have a successful call, AKA you reach the host by using the ping command you get 0 exit code. if you don't reach the host or you enter the command wrongly you will get something different than 0.

Comment: **but no matter what ip address I put valid or not it says it's up**,  use a piece of paper and compare the logic in that statement to your answer, if the order was reversed then a good ip should say down and a bad ip should say up, not up for both a bad and a good ip.

Comment: Are you working in a Linux / Mac? if that's the case the work, Sorry I can't check on a Windows. You can try it with you localhost or stackoverflow.com as the hostname.